# Multiple background image tilt dividers for sections

Tags: css, sections, divider, elementor

my first question here, but looooong time reader and eater.

So here's what I'm trying to achieve for a client that really wants it. [Website example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXizj.jpg)

I have no problems doing the tilt dividers, but I need to remove the area "behind" the background image that I have made the tilts etc on. So the section seamlessly go in to each other (like the image).

Here's my dev enviroment
http://celina.wonderbird.se/

This is just 30 mins of work so far. But as you see, I would like the dividers to be like that (or similar), but then the background image of the next section to be in the "white" areas of the section previous to it.

Any theories ?

//Christian

Comment: http://matthosch.github.io/mauna_kea/ appears to be close to the given website example - angled dividers are produced by performing a `transform(rotate(-5.5deg))`, with a corresponding `transform(rotate(5.5deg))` to re-orient the text (obviously, this would mean pre-rotating the background images 5.5 degrees).

Comment: check this: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ not too crossBrowser friendly but easy to achieve what you want. you can clip front divs and use background on divs behind. 
else you can use the pseudo classes to give diagnoal backgrounds (rotate them) and play with the overflow visibility to achieve the triangles